# POJO class for dog.ceo/dog-api

Tags: android

How POJO class must be look like in that API:
[https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all][1]

I've created next two classes, but something works not correctly.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;        
import java.util.List;

public class DogsKindsData {
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private List<DogKind> dogsKinds;

    public List<DogKind> getDogsKinds() {
        return dogsKinds;
    }
}
```

and the model

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class DogKind implements Parcelable {
    private String kind;
    private String imageString;
}
```

This is my implementation, but it doesn't work.

I've created the method that perfectly works with other POJO classes

```
public <T> T parseInputStream(InputStream inputStream, Class<T> classType) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    inputStream.read(buffer);
    inputStream.close();
    return gson.fromJson(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"), classType);
}
```

I use that method in next way:

```
DogsKindsData dogsKindsData = jsonParser.parseInputStream(inputStream, DogsKindsData.class);
```

But it says:

```
Process: com.andersen.dogsapp, PID: 6115
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 32 path $.message
```

Comment: I saw the JSON response and I dont think its a good data which you show, it has a "message" JSONObject and number of JSONArrays with different name containing nothing inside, please change the JSON response format, try to make it clean.

Comment: In fact i get that json. I see it in log. But i have a problem to parse that one in POJO. What do you mean "to change JSON response" ?

Comment: I mean try to change the data structure in the JSON you get, its difficult to extract data from the JSON you get from it..

Comment: I understand that Gson expects some another format but what exactly should i change i don't understand

Comment: {
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "baz": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  }
}

Comment: See this JSON object example, try to make something like this with your own key and types of dog list.

Comment: I'll try, thank you! But i need to know the POJO model in java code for that API. Unfortunately your json example won't help me a lot

Comment: [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) will help you get your POJO from a clear JSON schema,, Hope this helps.

Comment: I know about this website, but i don't like the POJO class's structure that it generates for this case. I believe that there is a much proper decision. Because it is very ugly decision to create a million fields of List<Object>. That's why i asked this question here.

Comment: it all boils down to the structure of the JSON you provide, again the JSON structure you have is not good, it will not help you in the project forward, if you can, you should make JSON structure in a better way.

Comment: I cannot change that API and its JSON structure, that's not mine

Answer (score 0):

```
        import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
        import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

        public class DogModel {

        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private String status;
        @SerializedName("message")
        @Expose
        private Message message;

        public String getStatus() {
        return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
        }

        public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
        }

        }


    *****************************************************************


    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Message {

    @SerializedName("affenpinscher")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> affenpinscher = null;
    @SerializedName("african")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> african = null;
    @SerializedName("airedale")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> airedale = null;
    @SerializedName("akita")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> akita = null;
    @SerializedName("appenzeller")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> appenzeller = null;
    @SerializedName("basenji")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> basenji = null;
    @SerializedName("beagle")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> beagle = null;
    @SerializedName("bluetick")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> bluetick = null;
    @SerializedName("borzoi")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> borzoi = null;
    @SerializedName("bouvier")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> bouvier = null;
    @SerializedName("boxer")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> boxer = null;
    @SerializedName("brabancon")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> brabancon = null;
    @SerializedName("briard")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> briard = null;
    @SerializedName("bulldog")
    @Expose
    private List<String> bulldog = null;
    @SerializedName("bullterrier")
    @Expose
    private List<String> bullterrier = null;
    @SerializedName("cairn")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> cairn = null;
    @SerializedName("cattledog")
    @Expose
    private List<String> cattledog = null;
    @SerializedName("chihuahua")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> chihuahua = null;
    @SerializedName("chow")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> chow = null;
    @SerializedName("clumber")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> clumber = null;
    @SerializedName("collie")
    @Expose
    private List<String> collie = null;
    @SerializedName("coonhound")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> coonhound = null;
    @SerializedName("corgi")
    @Expose
    private List<String> corgi = null;
    @SerializedName("cotondetulear")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> cotondetulear = null;
    @SerializedName("dachshund")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> dachshund = null;
    @SerializedName("dalmatian")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> dalmatian = null;
    @SerializedName("dane")
    @Expose
    private List<String> dane = null;
    @SerializedName("deerhound")
    @Expose
    private List<String> deerhound = null;
    @SerializedName("dhole")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> dhole = null;
    @SerializedName("dingo")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> dingo = null;
    @SerializedName("doberman")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> doberman = null;
    @SerializedName("elkhound")
    @Expose
    private List<String> elkhound = null;
    @SerializedName("entlebucher")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> entlebucher = null;
    @SerializedName("eskimo")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> eskimo = null;
    @SerializedName("germanshepherd")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> germanshepherd = null;
    @SerializedName("greyhound")
    @Expose
    private List<String> greyhound = null;
    @SerializedName("groenendael")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> groenendael = null;
    @SerializedName("hound")
    @Expose
    private List<String> hound = null;
    @SerializedName("husky")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> husky = null;
    @SerializedName("keeshond")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> keeshond = null;
    @SerializedName("kelpie")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> kelpie = null;
    @SerializedName("komondor")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> komondor = null;
    @SerializedName("kuvasz")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> kuvasz = null;
    @SerializedName("labrador")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> labrador = null;
    @SerializedName("leonberg")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> leonberg = null;
    @SerializedName("lhasa")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> lhasa = null;
    @SerializedName("malamute")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> malamute = null;
    @SerializedName("malinois")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> malinois = null;
    @SerializedName("maltese")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> maltese = null;
    @SerializedName("mastiff")
    @Expose
    private List<String> mastiff = null;
    @SerializedName("mexicanhairless")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> mexicanhairless = null;
    @SerializedName("mix")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> mix = null;
    @SerializedName("mountain")
    @Expose
    private List<String> mountain = null;
    @SerializedName("newfoundland")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> newfoundland = null;
    @SerializedName("otterhound")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> otterhound = null;
    @SerializedName("papillon")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> papillon = null;
    @SerializedName("pekinese")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> pekinese = null;
    @SerializedName("pembroke")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> pembroke = null;
    @SerializedName("pinscher")
    @Expose
    private List<String> pinscher = null;
    @SerializedName("pointer")
    @Expose
    private List<String> pointer = null;
    @SerializedName("pomeranian")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> pomeranian = null;
    @SerializedName("poodle")
    @Expose
    private List<String> poodle = null;
    @SerializedName("pug")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> pug = null;
    @SerializedName("puggle")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> puggle = null;
    @SerializedName("pyrenees")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> pyrenees = null;
    @SerializedName("redbone")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> redbone = null;
    @SerializedName("retriever")
    @Expose
    private List<String> retriever = null;
    @SerializedName("ridgeback")
    @Expose
    private List<String> ridgeback = null;
    @SerializedName("rottweiler")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> rottweiler = null;
    @SerializedName("saluki")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> saluki = null;
    @SerializedName("samoyed")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> samoyed = null;
    @SerializedName("schipperke")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> schipperke = null;
    @SerializedName("schnauzer")
    @Expose
    private List<String> schnauzer = null;
    @SerializedName("setter")
    @Expose
    private List<String> setter = null;
    @SerializedName("sheepdog")
    @Expose
    private List<String> sheepdog = null;
    @SerializedName("shiba")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> shiba = null;
    @SerializedName("shihtzu")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> shihtzu = null;
    @SerializedName("spaniel")
    @Expose
    private List<String> spaniel = null;
    @SerializedName("springer")
    @Expose
    private List<String> springer = null;
    @SerializedName("stbernard")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> stbernard = null;
    @SerializedName("terrier")
    @Expose
    private List<String> terrier = null;
    @SerializedName("vizsla")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> vizsla = null;
    @SerializedName("weimaraner")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> weimaraner = null;
    @SerializedName("whippet")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> whippet = null;
    @SerializedName("wolfhound")
    @Expose
    private List<String> wolfhound = null;

    public List<Object> getAffenpinscher() {
    return affenpinscher;
    }

    public void setAffenpinscher(List<Object> affenpinscher) {
    this.affenpinscher = affenpinscher;
    }

    public List<Object> getAfrican() {
    return african;
    }

    public void setAfrican(List<Object> african) {
    this.african = african;
    }

    public List<Object> getAiredale() {
    return airedale;
    }

    public void setAiredale(List<Object> airedale) {
    this.airedale = airedale;
    }

    public List<Object> getAkita() {
    return akita;
    }

    public void setAkita(List<Object> akita) {
    this.akita = akita;
    }

    public List<Object> getAppenzeller() {
    return appenzeller;
    }

    public void setAppenzeller(List<Object> appenzeller) {
    this.appenzeller = appenzeller;
    }

    public List<Object> getBasenji() {
    return basenji;
    }

    public void setBasenji(List<Object> basenji) {
    this.basenji = basenji;
    }

    public List<Object> getBeagle() {
    return beagle;
    }

    public void setBeagle(List<Object> beagle) {
    this.beagle = beagle;
    }

    public List<Object> getBluetick() {
    return bluetick;
    }

    public void setBluetick(List<Object> bluetick) {
    this.bluetick = bluetick;
    }

    public List<Object> getBorzoi() {
    return borzoi;
    }

    public void setBorzoi(List<Object> borzoi) {
    this.borzoi = borzoi;
    }

    public List<Object> getBouvier() {
    return bouvier;
    }

    public void setBouvier(List<Object> bouvier) {
    this.bouvier = bouvier;
    }

    public List<Object> getBoxer() {
    return boxer;
    }

    public void setBoxer(List<Object> boxer) {
    this.boxer = boxer;
    }

    public List<Object> getBrabancon() {
    return brabancon;
    }

    public void setBrabancon(List<Object> brabancon) {
    this.brabancon = brabancon;
    }

    public List<Object> getBriard() {
    return briard;
    }

    public void setBriard(List<Object> briard) {
    this.briard = briard;
    }

    public List<String> getBulldog() {
    return bulldog;
    }

    public void setBulldog(List<String> bulldog) {
    this.bulldog = bulldog;
    }

    public List<String> getBullterrier() {
    return bullterrier;
    }

    public void setBullterrier(List<String> bullterrier) {
    this.bullterrier = bullterrier;
    }

    public List<Object> getCairn() {
    return cairn;
    }

    public void setCairn(List<Object> cairn) {
    this.cairn = cairn;
    }

    public List<String> getCattledog() {
    return cattledog;
    }

    public void setCattledog(List<String> cattledog) {
    this.cattledog = cattledog;
    }

    public List<Object> getChihuahua() {
    return chihuahua;
    }

    public void setChihuahua(List<Object> chihuahua) {
    this.chihuahua = chihuahua;
    }

    public List<Object> getChow() {
    return chow;
    }

    public void setChow(List<Object> chow) {
    this.chow = chow;
    }

    public List<Object> getClumber() {
    return clumber;
    }

    public void setClumber(List<Object> clumber) {
    this.clumber = clumber;
    }

    public List<String> getCollie() {
    return collie;
    }

    public void setCollie(List<String> collie) {
    this.collie = collie;
    }

    public List<Object> getCoonhound() {
    return coonhound;
    }

    public void setCoonhound(List<Object> coonhound) {
    this.coonhound = coonhound;
    }

    public List<String> getCorgi() {
    return corgi;
    }

    public void setCorgi(List<String> corgi) {
    this.corgi = corgi;
    }

    public List<Object> getCotondetulear() {
    return cotondetulear;
    }

    public void setCotondetulear(List<Object> cotondetulear) {
    this.cotondetulear = cotondetulear;
    }

    public List<Object> getDachshund() {
    return dachshund;
    }

    public void setDachshund(List<Object> dachshund) {
    this.dachshund = dachshund;
    }

    public List<Object> getDalmatian() {
    return dalmatian;
    }

    public void setDalmatian(List<Object> dalmatian) {
    this.dalmatian = dalmatian;
    }

    public List<String> getDane() {
    return dane;
    }

    public void setDane(List<String> dane) {
    this.dane = dane;
    }

    public List<String> getDeerhound() {
    return deerhound;
    }

    public void setDeerhound(List<String> deerhound) {
    this.deerhound = deerhound;
    }

    public List<Object> getDhole() {
    return dhole;
    }

    public void setDhole(List<Object> dhole) {
    this.dhole = dhole;
    }

    public List<Object> getDingo() {
    return dingo;
    }

    public void setDingo(List<Object> dingo) {
    this.dingo = dingo;
    }

    public List<Object> getDoberman() {
    return doberman;
    }

    public void setDoberman(List<Object> doberman) {
    this.doberman = doberman;
    }

    public List<String> getElkhound() {
    return elkhound;
    }

    public void setElkhound(List<String> elkhound) {
    this.elkhound = elkhound;
    }

    public List<Object> getEntlebucher() {
    return entlebucher;
    }

    public void setEntlebucher(List<Object> entlebucher) {
    this.entlebucher = entlebucher;
    }

    public List<Object> getEskimo() {
    return eskimo;
    }

    public void setEskimo(List<Object> eskimo) {
    this.eskimo = eskimo;
    }

    public List<Object> getGermanshepherd() {
    return germanshepherd;
    }

    public void setGermanshepherd(List<Object> germanshepherd) {
    this.germanshepherd = germanshepherd;
    }

    public List<String> getGreyhound() {
    return greyhound;
    }

    public void setGreyhound(List<String> greyhound) {
    this.greyhound = greyhound;
    }

    public List<Object> getGroenendael() {
    return groenendael;
    }

    public void setGroenendael(List<Object> groenendael) {
    this.groenendael = groenendael;
    }

    public List<String> getHound() {
    return hound;
    }

    public void setHound(List<String> hound) {
    this.hound = hound;
    }

    public List<Object> getHusky() {
    return husky;
    }

    public void setHusky(List<Object> husky) {
    this.husky = husky;
    }

    public List<Object> getKeeshond() {
    return keeshond;
    }

    public void setKeeshond(List<Object> keeshond) {
    this.keeshond = keeshond;
    }

    public List<Object> getKelpie() {
    return kelpie;
    }

    public void setKelpie(List<Object> kelpie) {
    this.kelpie = kelpie;
    }

    public List<Object> getKomondor() {
    return komondor;
    }

    public void setKomondor(List<Object> komondor) {
    this.komondor = komondor;
    }

    public List<Object> getKuvasz() {
    return kuvasz;
    }

    public void setKuvasz(List<Object> kuvasz) {
    this.kuvasz = kuvasz;
    }

    public List<Object> getLabrador() {
    return labrador;
    }

    public void setLabrador(List<Object> labrador) {
    this.labrador = labrador;
    }

    public List<Object> getLeonberg() {
    return leonberg;
    }

    public void setLeonberg(List<Object> leonberg) {
    this.leonberg = leonberg;
    }

    public List<Object> getLhasa() {
    return lhasa;
    }

    public void setLhasa(List<Object> lhasa) {
    this.lhasa = lhasa;
    }

    public List<Object> getMalamute() {
    return malamute;
    }

    public void setMalamute(List<Object> malamute) {
    this.malamute = malamute;
    }

    public List<Object> getMalinois() {
    return malinois;
    }

    public void setMalinois(List<Object> malinois) {
    this.malinois = malinois;
    }

    public List<Object> getMaltese() {
    return maltese;
    }

    public void setMaltese(List<Object> maltese) {
    this.maltese = maltese;
    }

    public List<String> getMastiff() {
    return mastiff;
    }

    public void setMastiff(List<String> mastiff) {
    this.mastiff = mastiff;
    }

    public List<Object> getMexicanhairless() {
    return mexicanhairless;
    }

    public void setMexicanhairless(List<Object> mexicanhairless) {
    this.mexicanhairless = mexicanhairless;
    }

    public List<Object> getMix() {
    return mix;
    }

    public void setMix(List<Object> mix) {
    this.mix = mix;
    }

    public List<String> getMountain() {
    return mountain;
    }

    public void setMountain(List<String> mountain) {
    this.mountain = mountain;
    }

    public List<Object> getNewfoundland() {
    return newfoundland;
    }

    public void setNewfoundland(List<Object> newfoundland) {
    this.newfoundland = newfoundland;
    }

    public List<Object> getOtterhound() {
    return otterhound;
    }

    public void setOtterhound(List<Object> otterhound) {
    this.otterhound = otterhound;
    }

    public List<Object> getPapillon() {
    return papillon;
    }

    public void setPapillon(List<Object> papillon) {
    this.papillon = papillon;
    }

    public List<Object> getPekinese() {
    return pekinese;
    }

    public void setPekinese(List<Object> pekinese) {
    this.pekinese = pekinese;
    }

    public List<Object> getPembroke() {
    return pembroke;
    }

    public void setPembroke(List<Object> pembroke) {
    this.pembroke = pembroke;
    }

    public List<String> getPinscher() {
    return pinscher;
    }

    public void setPinscher(List<String> pinscher) {
    this.pinscher = pinscher;
    }

    public List<String> getPointer() {
    return pointer;
    }

    public void setPointer(List<String> pointer) {
    this.pointer = pointer;
    }

    public List<Object> getPomeranian() {
    return pomeranian;
    }

    public void setPomeranian(List<Object> pomeranian) {
    this.pomeranian = pomeranian;
    }

    public List<String> getPoodle() {
    return poodle;
    }

    public void setPoodle(List<String> poodle) {
    this.poodle = poodle;
    }

    public List<Object> getPug() {
    return pug;
    }

    public void setPug(List<Object> pug) {
    this.pug = pug;
    }

    public List<Object> getPuggle() {
    return puggle;
    }

    public void setPuggle(List<Object> puggle) {
    this.puggle = puggle;
    }

    public List<Object> getPyrenees() {
    return pyrenees;
    }

    public void setPyrenees(List<Object> pyrenees) {
    this.pyrenees = pyrenees;
    }

    public List<Object> getRedbone() {
    return redbone;
    }

    public void setRedbone(List<Object> redbone) {
    this.redbone = redbone;
    }

    public List<String> getRetriever() {
    return retriever;
    }

    public void setRetriever(List<String> retriever) {
    this.retriever = retriever;
    }

    public List<String> getRidgeback() {
    return ridgeback;
    }

    public void setRidgeback(List<String> ridgeback) {
    this.ridgeback = ridgeback;
    }

    public List<Object> getRottweiler() {
    return rottweiler;
    }

    public void setRottweiler(List<Object> rottweiler) {
    this.rottweiler = rottweiler;
    }

    public List<Object> getSaluki() {
    return saluki;
    }

    public void setSaluki(List<Object> saluki) {
    this.saluki = saluki;
    }

    public List<Object> getSamoyed() {
    return samoyed;
    }

    public void setSamoyed(List<Object> samoyed) {
    this.samoyed = samoyed;
    }

    public List<Object> getSchipperke() {
    return schipperke;
    }

    public void setSchipperke(List<Object> schipperke) {
    this.schipperke = schipperke;
    }

    public List<String> getSchnauzer() {
    return schnauzer;
    }

    public void setSchnauzer(List<String> schnauzer) {
    this.schnauzer = schnauzer;
    }

    public List<String> getSetter() {
    return setter;
    }

    public void setSetter(List<String> setter) {
    this.setter = setter;
    }

    public List<String> getSheepdog() {
    return sheepdog;
    }

    public void setSheepdog(List<String> sheepdog) {
    this.sheepdog = sheepdog;
    }

    public List<Object> getShiba() {
    return shiba;
    }

    public void setShiba(List<Object> shiba) {
    this.shiba = shiba;
    }

    public List<Object> getShihtzu() {
    return shihtzu;
    }

    public void setShihtzu(List<Object> shihtzu) {
    this.shihtzu = shihtzu;
    }

    public List<String> getSpaniel() {
    return spaniel;
    }

    public void setSpaniel(List<String> spaniel) {
    this.spaniel = spaniel;
    }

    public List<String> getSpringer() {
    return springer;
    }

    public void setSpringer(List<String> springer) {
    this.springer = springer;
    }

    public List<Object> getStbernard() {
    return stbernard;
    }

    public void setStbernard(List<Object> stbernard) {
    this.stbernard = stbernard;
    }

    public List<String> getTerrier() {
    return terrier;
    }

    public void setTerrier(List<String> terrier) {
    this.terrier = terrier;
    }

    public List<Object> getVizsla() {
    return vizsla;
    }

    public void setVizsla(List<Object> vizsla) {
    this.vizsla = vizsla;
    }

    public List<Object> getWeimaraner() {
    return weimaraner;
    }

    public void setWeimaraner(List<Object> weimaraner) {
    this.weimaraner = weimaraner;
    }

    public List<Object> getWhippet() {
    return whippet;
    }

    public void setWhippet(List<Object> whippet) {
    this.whippet = whippet;
    }

    public List<String> getWolfhound() {
    return wolfhound;
    }

    public void setWolfhound(List<String> wolfhound) {
    this.wolfhound = wolfhound;
    }

    }


*******************************************************************

Parse this using GSON library

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  DogModel dogModel = gson.fromJson(responseString, DogModel.class);//responseString is the response received from server
```

/**
*
* It will be better if you structure the JSON in a better way
* 
*
*/

Comment: I'm afraid that is not clean code. It was also my first thought, but i doubt that it's correct

Comment: It not clean code. But it will work for the JSON response. It would be better if you can rework on structure of the response.

Comment: Where should i have to structure the JSON response? What do you mean?

Comment: You meant to create custom deserializer class?